# Fazer um combobox mostrar dados do banco de dados?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estou aprendendo do zero , e estou com dificuldade de fazer a combobox mostrar uma lista de países de uma tabela do banco de dados. estou tentando fazer por código e mesmo tentando varias formas que fui achando na net não tenho conseguido , ela sempre fica em branco na hora de rodar.

segue código

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strConexao = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRES;Initial Catalog=Medalhas_Paraolimpiadas;Integrated Security=True";
        string Query = "SELECT Pais FROM Table_1";

        SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(strConexao);//atribui ao objeto conexao ao método de conexão ao banco de dados
        conexao.Open();                                 //abre objeto

        try
        {
            SqlCommand da = new SqlCommand(Query, conexao);
            SqlDataReader reader = da.ExecuteReader();   //retorna dados resultantes da consulta SQL 
            DataTable tb = new DataTable();             //estrutura da tabela do BD ou de outra fonte
            tb.Load(reader);                            //carrega dados na tabela de acordo com a instrução SQL passada        
            DataRow row = tb.NewRow();                  //representa uma linha de dados em um DataTable
            row["descricao"] = "";                      //para não gerar valor nulo e evitar erro de execução    
            tb.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);                   //insere nova linha na coleção no local especificado
            comboBox1.DataSource = tb;             //atribui o objeto DataTable a instância do SQL Server a ser conectada
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Pais";         //obtemos o valor do membro (código da descrição)
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Id_Pais";      //obtemos a descrição do membro
            reader.Close();                             //fecha objeto
            reader.Dispose();                           //liberamos o objeto da memória
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível preencher o ComboBox\n\nErro:" + ex,"Erro!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            conexao.Close(); //fecha conexão    
            conexao.Dispose(); //liberamos o objeto da memória
        }
```

Estou tentando criar um form que mostre o quadro de medalhas das olimpiadas. criei um bd e uma tabela com as colunas id_pais,Pais,ouro,parta,bronze e total.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá,

Primeiro que, você colocou o código na ação `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`, ou seja, ele só vai rodar seu código quando for selecionado alguma opção dentro do comboBox, mas como o código ainda não rodou, não vai existir nenhuma opção pra escolher né?

O que eu recomendo fazer é criar uma função pra ser executada quando o Form for aberto.

Aqui eu tenho meu codigo de como preenchi meu comboBox:

```
void Fillcombovendedor()
        {

            string Query = "select * from FUNCIONARIOS";
            MySqlCommand cmddatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, BDconnection);

            try
            {
                BDconnection.Open();
                reader = cmddatabase.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    string sName = reader.GetString("NOME");
                    CMBvendedor.Items.Add(sName);

                }
                BDconnection.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }

        }
```

Você precisa achar dentro do código do seu Form algo mais ou menos assim:

```
public Form1()
        {

        }
```

Ali onde está o Form1, vai ser o nome que você deu pro seu Form.

Então, dentro desses {} você chama sua função, no meu caso, a minha se chama `Fillcombovendedor`, então ficou assim:

```
public Form1()
            {
             Fillcombovendedor();
            }
```

essa função vai ser chamada sempre que o Form for aberto